# Android ontouch example

Tags: android

I have an example which I collect from Internet.

```
public class MprojectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageView itan2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        itan2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView18);

        itan2.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


           if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) itan2.getLayoutParams();

                    int x =(int)  event.getRawX();
                    int y =(int)  event.getRawY();

                    mParams.leftMargin =  x-236;
                    mParams.topMargin =  y-565;
                    itan2.setLayoutParams(mParams);


           }      
                return true;
            }
        });

                  }

}
```

In this example I subtract 236 and 565 with x and y.What are these values actually.how to find them with dynamic coding?

Answer (score 1):

It is used to create the relative layout, there is nothing complex about it, it's really simple.

x-236 means you are setting a point on x-axis 236 unit away from the left top of the screen.
y-565 means you are setting a point on y-axis 565 unit away from the left top of the screen.

by using those two values and left top value (0,0) you are creating a layout to show your image ( which is itan2 in this example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, please edit it. If you want to learn something more about getRawX and getRawY, please have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html which says:

> public final float getRawX ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Returns the original raw X coordinate of this
>   event. For touch events on the screen, this is the original location
>   of the event on the screen, before it had been adjusted for the
>   containing window and views.

Same for getRawY()

Comment: I have to know the value which I substracted(236,565).why I subtract it from x and y. and what are these values actually.

Comment: Well, there are many ways on how you could archive it. For example you can show this values on the screen by using Toast. You can use debugger and set a breakpoint on that line etc...

Comment: But I have to write it dynamically...not statically.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to use dynamic programming to view variable value? If you want to see,  what value is inside it you should do it like I said before. What are you trying to archive...?